# How can I play an Adobe Flash video on my Google TV?

Tags: adobe-flash, google-tv

I cannot open a Jib Jab video on my Google TV that someone sent me. It says that I have to have the latest version on Adobe Flash.  I thought it came with the latest Google Chrome browser, that's what I have, but it won't play.  Can someone tell me how to fix this?  I have Sony Google TV NSZ-GS7.

Comment: Which Google TV device do you have?

Comment: I have Sony Google TV Model #NSZ GS7

Comment: This model has ARM-based processor, which means it will be upgraded to the newest Google TV firmware version once it's released.  Unfortunately in that version Google completely removed Flash, since Adobe is no longer supporting it.  Bottom line - there is no way to play that flash video on Google TV.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe stopped supporting Flash player on Android, and removed their app from Play Store.  GTV's Chrome browser's Flash plugin will remain at whatever version it currently is, and will [no longer receive any updates](https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/35328/c/65,66/p/47329,70712,70715,70717/).

Bottom line is that there is no way to play that video on your Google TV device.